# Angular conditional container element

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a large chunk of HTML in an `ng-repeat` that for certain elements has a container element and for others it does not. I'm currently achieving this with two `ng-if`s:

```
<strike ng-if="elem.flag">
  … <!-- several lines of directives handling other branching cases -->
</strike>
<div ng-if="!elem.flag">
  … <!-- those same several lines copied-and-pasted -->
</div>
```

While this works, it means I have to remember copy-and-paste any edits, which is not only inelegant but also prone to bugs. Ideally, I could DRY this up with something like the following (inspired by `ng-class` syntax):

```
<ng-element="{'strike':flag, 'div':(!flag)}">
  … <!-- lots of code just once! -->
</ng-element>
```

Is there any way to achieve a similarly non-repetitive solution for this case?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make such directive yourself.
2. You can use `ng-include` to include the same content into both elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive which will `transclude` the content based on condition. For tranclusion you could use `ng-transclude` drirective, in directive template. Also you need to set `transclude: true`.

**HTML**

```
<my-directive ng-attr-element="{{elem.flag ? 'strike': 'div'}}">
    <div> Common content</div>
</my-directive>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($parse, $interpolate) {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    replace: false, //will replace the directive element with directive template
    template: function(element, attrs) {
      //this seems hacky statement
      var result = $interpolate(attrs.element)(element.parent().scope);
      var html = '<'+ result + ' ng-transclude></'+result+'>';
      return html;
    }
  }
})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BQNUtgMkI1ASA4P5MN3I?p=preview)

Comment: @eirikir does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the effect you desire is to have the text within your tag be striked through based on the condition of the elem.flag:
You could simply use the ng-class as follows

```js
angular.module('ngClassExample', [])
  .controller('elemController', Controller1);

function Controller1() {
  vm = this;  
  vm.flag = true;
  
    vm.clickItem = clickItem
    
    function clickItem() {
      // Toggle the flag
      vm.flag = !vm.flag;
    };
}
```

```css
.strikethrough{
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='ngClassExample' ng-controller="elemController as elem">
  <div ng-class="{strikethrough: elem.flag}" ng-click="elem.clickItem()">
   element content should be sticked through: {{elem.flag}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a directive

```
module.directive('myFlag', function() {
  var tmpl1 = '<strike>...</strike>';
  var tmpl2 = '<div>...</div>';
  return {
    scope: {
      myFlag: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.html(''); // empty element
      if (scope.myFlag) {
        element.append(tmpl1);
      } else {
        element.append(tmpl2);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

And you just use it like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" my-flag="item.flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-transclude :
Create your directive :

```
<container-directive strike="flag">
    <!-- your html here-->
</container-directive>
```

Then in your directive do something like :

```
<strike ng-if="strike">
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</strike>
<div ng-if="!strike">
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```